# SKSpriteNode Stuck with init(edgeLoopFrom:) - SKPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a separate class called "Floor" with below.

```
class Floor: SKNode {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        //let edgeFrame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 1,y: 1), size: CGSize(width: 1078, height: 1950))
        //self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: edgeFrame)

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody

        // Apply a physics body to the node
       // self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

        // Set the bit mask properties
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorCategory
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = nailDropCategory
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemted")
    }
}
```

I basically have falling SKSpriteNode's that start at the top of the screen and goes to the bottom where it touches the "Floor" and removes itself then restarts from top again. Issue I'm having is all my SKSpriteNode keeps getting stuck on top and not falling through the border around the frame of the screen. How can I tell my application to ignore those specific nodes and let them in? Appreciate any help!

---

Here is the object that is moving left and right on the screen but it just falls off the side of the screen without the edgeLoop

```
if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft {
                balloon.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * -500.0, dy: 0)
            } else {
                balloon.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 500.0, dy: 0)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that your objects are hitting the top boundary of the edge loop and not being able to make it into the scene.

there is several ways you can do you this, if you absolutely needed the edge loop on the sides I would suggest elongating the loop to be higher than the scene and creating the objects inside the loop but above the visible area. However since you haven't given any indication that you actually need the loop on the sides all I would do is get rid of the edge loop detection.

create a box that is the width of the scene and say a 100px high then put a physics body on it of type `floorCategory`. then put this box 50 px below the bottom of the screen. Assuming that your floor sprite box has an anchorPoint of 0.5, 0.5 this will hide the box below the screen and the top of the box will sit flush with the bottom of the screen.

Now you will be able to detect when your objects hit the bottom of the screen and you will no longer have to worry about them passing through the edge loop at the top.

OR

an example of elongating the loop would be...

You create a rectangle taller than the screen (green border in the image) to apply the edge loop to, not to the screen size itself

[image]

Comment: The one issue is I have an SKSpriteNode image on the bottom of the display that basically dodges the objects falling from top. I just honestly have the edgeLoop so that object at the bottom doesn't go off the screen because it does right now since I updated Xcode 9 and had to update my app for iPhone X. If I can just some how protect my node from leaving the side of the screen along with detect when the objects fall from the top of the screen and off to the bottom where it hits the "floor" and removes but I can't seem to figure it out. Your answer was very helpful though!

Comment: I've added an image for elongating the loop, if that helps

Comment: I get what you're talking about Rob, basically instead of creating the boundaries around the whole frame, I would just need to do it at the very bottom of the screen. This is, this box helps keep a SKSpriteNode image I have at the bottom of the screen (Not under) that slides off the screen when I tilt my iPhone left or right since that's how I set the node to do. If I can some how set that node to stay in the screen without the edgeloop around the whole frame and at the bottom instead then I'd love to do it this way

Comment: It's Ron ;)
Rob is the other guy. that's why I added the image to show you another alternative that would still give you the edge loop but allow you to drop your items on the screen

Comment: just an FYI, edge loops are more expensive than solid boxes, so you may want to just place 2 bumper nodes on the sides and a remove node at the bottom

Comment: I totally agree, I never use them myself. I wrestle sometimes with how much info to put into an answer in order to keep it as simple as possible. Good comment though.

Comment: Oh your answer is fine, that is why I gave an upvote,  The comment was more of an "advance" step to take.  With edge loop around the entire scene, that SKPhysicsBody is going to constantly fire (Unless optimized of course) to check if a body is at an edge.  I know with Scenekit, there is a presence of `didUpdateContact`, so I have no idea if SpriteKit does it too, and we just do not have access to it.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Why does my node turn sideways and stuff when it touches the bumper nodes? I don't want my SKSpriteNode to be rotating positions when it collides with it

Comment: Turn off allowsRotation